# NullPointerException android app

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I already know what a nullpointerexception is, but Im not able to find it in my own code. I hope you guys can see it

here is the log:

```
12-04 06:21:36.866    1687-1687/com.example.thelegendaryturk.theneckoptimizer E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.thelegendaryturk.theneckoptimizer, PID: 1687
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.thelegendaryturk.theneckoptimizer.RegisterActivity$1.onClick(RegisterActivity.java:63)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

---

Here is the RegisterActivity.java(line 63 is highlighted with ***)

```
public class RegisterActivity extends Activity {
    Button btnRegister;
    Button btnLinkToLogin;
    EditText inputFullName;
    EditText inputEmail;
    EditText inputPassword;
    TextView registerErrorMsg;

    // JSON Response node names
    private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static String KEY_ERROR = "error";
    private static String KEY_ERROR_MSG = "error_msg";
    private static String KEY_UID = "uid";
    private static String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.register);

        // Importing all assets like buttons, text fields
        inputFullName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerName);
        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerEmail);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerPassword);
        btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
        btnLinkToLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToLoginScreen);
        registerErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.register_error);

        // Register Button Click event
        btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String name = inputFullName.getText().toString();
                String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
                String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
                UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
                JSONObject json = userFunction.registerUser(name, email, password);

                // check for login response
                try {
                *** if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                        registerErrorMsg.setText("");
                        String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
                        if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                            // user successfully registred
                            // Store user details in SQLite Database
                            DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                            JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                            // Clear all previous data in database
                            userFunction.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                            db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_NAME), json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL), json.getString(KEY_UID), json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));                        
                            // Launch Dashboard Screen
                            Intent dashboard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DashboardActivity.class);
                            // Close all views before launching Dashboard
                            dashboard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            startActivity(dashboard);
                            // Close Registration Screen
                            finish();
                        }else{
                            // Error in registration
                            registerErrorMsg.setText("Error occured in registration");
                        }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        // Link to Login Screen
        btnLinkToLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                // Close Registration View
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is the UserFunction.java:

```
public class UserFunctions {

    public JSONParser jsonParser;

    private static String loginURL = "http://10.0.2.2/android_login_api/";
    private static String registerURL = "http://10.0.2.2/android_login_api/";

    private static String login_tag = "login";
    private static String register_tag = "register";

    // constructor
    public UserFunctions(){
        jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    }

    /**
     * function make Login Request
     * @param email
     * @param password
     * */
    public JSONObject loginUser(String email, String password){
        // Building Parameters
        JSONObject json;
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", login_tag));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(loginURL, params);
        // return json
        // Log.e("JSON", json.toString());
        return json;
    }

    /**
     * function make Login Request
     * @param name
     * @param email
     * @param password
     * */
    public JSONObject registerUser(String name, String email, String password){
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", register_tag));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

        // getting JSON Object
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(registerURL, params);
        // return json
        return json;
    }

    /**
     * Function get Login status
     * */
    public boolean isUserLoggedIn(Context context){
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
        int count = db.getRowCount();
        if(count > 0){
            // user logged in
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Function to logout user
     * Reset Database
     * */
    public boolean logoutUser(Context context){
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
        db.resetTables();
        return true;
    }

}
```

I think there is a simple solution but I am wasting my time for more than two hours now. Any help is welcome

Comment: where is highlighted line?

Comment: That doesn't look like the full stack trace. There is usually a 'caused at' line which says where the nullpointerexception was thrown from.

Comment: where is *** in your code? which line is causing NPE?

Comment: I highlighted the line

Comment: probably the variable "json" is null. You should use a debugger and investigate.

Comment: might be your json is null.

Comment: does userFunction.registerUser perform an http call?

Comment: @muhammetozer post your `userFunction ` class code.

Comment: so json is null or it doesn't have string "success"

Comment: I added userFunction.java

Comment: check the `json` object that you are returning from `loginUser` function. I think it's `null`

Comment: Whenever I see NPE, I post the same answer: NPE is one of the easiest problem to solve. You get the line where the error occures. If it has an own variable, check where it is filled, if it is not `null`. If an API call is used and returns `null`check the manual what such a result may mean, maybe add a check condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First check json then check KEY_SUCCESS :

```
if (json!=null && json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
```

Comment: YOU ARE THE MAN DUDE! IT WORKED. I WOULD KNOW YOU IN REAL LIFE, I WOULD BUY You a turkish kebab!!!

Answer (score 2):

your problem is in either :

```
JSONObject json = userFunction.registerUser(name, email, password);
```

OR:

```
json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS)
```

even if you don't get the corresponding `JSONObject` from the `userFunction` or the **String** called `KEY_SUCCESS` is referenced to a null value.

Comment: `getString()` throws `JSONException` when the mapping does not exist.

Comment: @BaileyS sure, but sometimes checking an object equality to null(eg. `if(obj != null)`) gives a **NullPointerException** if the comparison is must Not happened by null.

Comment: Quite right, the behavior of `getString( value )` is undefined when `value` is null, and certainly might cause NPE.  I just meant that if the value is not null and does not correspond to anything in the map, NPE is not thrown.

Comment: @BaileyS you are right, I think I stumbled a little when illustrating my answer, any way I corrected it

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is in Userfunction.registerUser()

```
json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(loginURL, params);
```

step in here at debugging or check by code if json == null

```
if(json == null)
   system.out.println("Error json object == null");
```

i think you really should find out why the jsonParser returns null at this point. Perhaps der url is not available?